# Uncaught ReferenceError: FirebaseApp is not defined or Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3, angularfire2

I am declaring the namespaces like:

```
declare namespace firebase.database.ServerValue {
    var TIMESTAMP: any
}
```

and getting this error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined

```
declare namespace FirebaseApp.Timestamp{
    var TIMESTAMP: any;
}
```

and getting error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: FirebaseApp is not defined

angularFire2 and firebase version:

```
"angularfire2": "^4.0.0-rc.1",
"firebase": "^4.1.3",
```

> cli packages:
>
> ```
> @ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.5.0 (C:\....\node_modules\@ionic\cli-plugin-cordova)
> @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.4.0 (C:\....\node_modules\@ionic\cli-plugin-ionic-angular)
> @ionic/cli-utils                : 1.6.0 (C:\....\node_modules\@ionic\cli-utils)
> ionic (Ionic CLI)               : 3.6.0 (C:\....\node_modules\ionic)
> ```
>
> global packages:
>
> ```
> Cordova CLI : 7.0.1
> ```
>
> local packages:
>
> ```
> @ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.4
> Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0
> Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.6.0
> ```
>
> System:
>
> ```
> Android SDK Tools : 25.2.5
> Node              : v6.11.1
> OS                : Windows 7
> npm               : 5.1.0
> ```

How to solve these issue? because I want to get the value of TIMESTEMP by declaring any of above mentioned namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved!

step1- Upgrading to AngularFire 5.0

Step2 -

```
.......
......
.....

import * as firebase from 'firebase';
export class .....  {
lastMessageTime: any;
   consturctor(){
      lastMessageTime = firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
    }
}
```